# Downloading a file for my vscode extension after activation

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I am developing a vscode extension, it needs to download a large file to work correctly. I have a logic that does it and keeps track of download progress so on vscode restart it continues from the place it stopped. After the file is downloaded my extension finishes activation and is ready for work.

```
async function downloadFile(url: string, path: string, progress: number, progressFilePath: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const file = fs.createWriteStream(path, { flags: 'a' });

        https.get(url, { headers: { Range: `bytes=${progress}-` } }, (response) => {
            const totalLength = parseInt(response.headers['content-length']!, 10);
            let downloaded = progress;

            response.on('data', (chunk) => {
                downloaded += chunk.length;
                const currentProgress = (downloaded / totalLength) * 100;
                fs.writeFileSync(progressFilePath, JSON.stringify({progress: downloaded}));
            });

            response.pipe(file, { end: false });

            response.on('end', () => {
                file.end();
                resolve(true);
            });
        }).on('error', (err) => {
            fs.unlink(path, () => {}); // Delete the file if download fails
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

My problem is that if user has more than 1 VSCode window open my extension has multiple copies and tries to download the file multiple time thus making the final file corrupted.

I tried creating a .lock file so that if it exists the extension doesn't download the file but waits for another window to download it before executing the rest of code.

```
if (fs.existsSync(lockFile)) {
        await new Promise(res => {
            const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
                if (fs.existsSync(path) && !fs.existsSync(progressFilePath)) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    res(true);
                }
            }, 1000);
        });
        return;
    }
```

With this approach I can't continue download if VSCode was closed before it finished downloading as on start it sees .lock file and decides that it should skip download. I also tried removing .lock file on extension `deactivate()` but for some reason it is not removed

```
export function deactivate(): Thenable<void> | undefined {
    fs.unlinkSync(lockFile);
}
```

Comment: 1. Warn users that they shouldn't close VS Code before the download ended, or they hit the download error. 2. Give them a "force download" option in your extension, so that they can help themselves. I don't think `deactivate` is guranteed to be called when VS Code exits.

Comment: oftentimes the users don't read what is written and don't do what is expected, also there might be many reasons for download to be stopped, it would be nice to have an ability to continue the download as the file is pretty big